# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' is returned when trying to determine the mode of a column in a data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

While trying to determine the mode of a particular column of a data the following error was returned:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv.txt', index_col='Loan_ID')
from scipy.stats import mode
mode((data['Gender'])) # determine mode of column Gender.
```

Question:
I understand the error is caused by missing values in the data. I need help with how to modify the 3rd line such that the missing values are dealt with and the mode displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all missings by `np.Nan` and u have param `nan_policy` in function mode

**nan_policy** : `{‘propagate’, ‘raise’, ‘omit’}`, optional
Defines how to handle when input contains nan. ‘propagate’ returns nan, ‘raise’ throws an error, ‘omit’ performs the calculations ignoring nan values. Default is ‘propagate’.

See [scipy.stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html)

Comment: Thanks Ashwel, could you help with details of the code to use for replacing missing values  with np.Nan

Comment: Ofc, could u post here result of data['Gender'].unique ?

Comment: Ashwel, output is long so I am going to send in batches:                <bound method Series.unique of Loan_ID
LP001002      Male
LP001003      Male
LP001005      Male
LP001006      Male
LP001008      Male
LP001011      Male
LP001013      Male
LP001014      Male
LP001018      Male
LP001020      Male
LP001024      Male
LP001027      Male
LP001028      Male
LP001029      Male
LP001030      Male
LP001032      Male
LP001034      Male
LP001036    Female
LP001038      Male
LP001041      Male

Comment: LP001043      Male
LP001046      Male
LP001047      Male

Comment: LP001050       NaN
LP001052      Male
LP001066      Male
LP001068      Male
LP001073      Male
LP001086      Male
LP001087    Female
             ...  
LP002911      Male
LP002912      Male
LP002916      Male
LP002917    Female
LP002925       NaN
LP002926      Male
LP002928      Male
LP002931      Male
LP002933       NaN
LP002936      Male

Comment: LP002938      Male
LP002940      Male
LP002941      Male
LP002943      Male
LP002945      Male
LP002948      Male
LP002949    Female
LP002950      Male
LP002953      Male
LP002958      Male
LP002959    Female
LP002960      Male
LP002961      Male
LP002964      Male
LP002974      Male
LP002978    Female
LP002979      Male
LP002983      Male
LP002984      Male
LP002990    Female
Name: Gender, Length: 614, dtype: object>